# Making Bootstrap button with an image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need to make a button that is an image so that when you click on it, it will do what the button is supposed to do. I'm making a carousel and trying to change the left and right buttons if you were wondering what I needed it for. At the bottom is the code I am trying to change. Instead of glyphicons I need it to be my own images.

```
</div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

Comment: Just replace your `span` with `img` then use some css to resize the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within both the left and right controls, replace these lines of code:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
```

with:

```
<img class="img-responsive center-block" src="./path/to/image.jpg" alt="Your Alt Text">
```

Without seeing the code in action, it's difficult to say, but you may need to resize your images—or the CSS that governs the size of the carousel controls—to make your switch display correctly. It shouldn't require too much tweaking, though.

Comment: That worked but now the buttons for the carousel aren't working... do you know how I could fix that?

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/?tra73602uv0w2cm that is a download link to the code. If you want a can make a fiddle or something..

Comment: or if you just want to view it go here: http://www.mediafire.com/view/tra73602uv0w2cm/index.html